# nltk.download('stopwords ') has permission error in Docker

Tags: python, docker

I have used `nltk.download('stopwords ')` in my python code. when I am running it through docker it is throwing me some error like below:

```
os.mkdir(download_dir)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/nltk_data'
```

and before that I got something like this:

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=18): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/apache-flask/apache-flask.wsgi'.

 mod_wsgi (pid=18): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/apache-flask/apache-flask.wsgi'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following command in your Dockerfile so that you may not need to do it in your Python script which could possibly solve the issue.

`RUN [ "python", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('all')" ]`

Comment: but the problem is it is installing in root. I want it to be installed in /var/www/nltk_data folder, hoe to do that through docker

Comment: You can mention the download path at `nltk.download('all', download_dir=' /var/www/nltk_data')`

Comment: yeah, actually after downloading it to the docker path I copied it to desired path through docker only